# Bounded component of the complement of a closed set

Tags: general-topology

In [this]
([Bounded components of complement of bounded planar domain are simply-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415064/bounded-components-of-complement-of-bounded-planar-domain-are-simply-connected)) Moishe Kohan says that if $E$ is a closed set and $U$ is a bounded component of the complement of $E$, then the boundary of $U$ is contained in $E$. What is the formal proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every open set $U$ can be expressed as sum of [maximal connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), say $U_{i\in I}$. Now because for fixed $k\in I$, $U_k$ is separated from $U\setminus U_k $, thus $\overline U\cap (U\U_k)=\emptyset$. It means, that the boundary of any component is contained in the complement of $U$, i.e.:
$$\overline {U_k}\setminus U_k\subset U^c$$

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. Assume $U$ is a bounded connected component of the complement of $E$. Then $U\setminus U_k=U\setminus U=\emptyset$! And then?

Comment: Then $\overline U \setminus U \subset U^c$ as well. That is, if $U$ is itself connected, then by definition its boundary is contained in the complement. But if $E^c=U$, then $U^c=E^{cc}=E$. As for $U$ being bounded, it is used further in Moishe Kohan's answer, but not needed here.

Comment: Let me explain more clearly the problem. There are non empty open sets $U$ and $V$ that are disjoint such that $E^c=U\cup V$, and $U$ is bounded. You prove that the boundary of $U$ is included into the complement of $U$(which is always true for any open set $U$). But could you please explain how do you go from there to conclude that the boundary of $U$ is in $E$?

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are maximal connected components, thus $U\cup V$ is not only disjoint, but also separated. Thus $\overline U \cap V=\emptyset$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separated_sets#Definitions

Comment: OK. But how to conclude that the boundary of $U$ is in $E$?

Comment: I'm afraid, I cannot put it simpler. This is direct consequence of boundary definition. Because  boundary $\overline U \setminus U$ is disjoint with $U$ and disjoint with $V$, it is subset of $(V\cup U)^c=E$.